# Google Checkout on checkout page in magento

Tags: magento, google-checkout

I want to display google checkout at one page checkout page in magento, so that customer will choose the payment options either he choose google checkout or he choose other like paypal.

I am using magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable google checkout from Admin.

Go to System->Configuration->on left side select sales->google API
Than select google checkout.

You also need to create  sandbox account for google checkout on google.

Comment: sorry i have done already it, but it display on shopping cart page only not in checkout page.

Comment: I have search and found that it appear only at shopping cart page and directly redirect  to google wallet not to magento checkout page..

Comment: yes... it display only on shopping cart page not on checkout page

Answer (score 0):

Add this lil snippet of code on your checkout page:

> php echo
>   $this->getLayout()->createBlock('googlecheckout/link')->setTemplate('googlecheckout/link.phtml')->toHtml();
>   ?>

add '<' to the beginning of the code, stackoverflow removes it